# How to solve: $(x + y^2)y’ = y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I think this question has been asked before.

Yet, i would like a hint before looking at the answers.

I have the equation:

$$
(x+y^2)y’ = y
$$

I don’t have even an idea how to start solving it. It’s not linear, substitution - I don’t see how it helps, x and y are together - not separate...

Any tips how to solve those things? (I prefer a hint more than a full answer).

Answer (score 4):

***HINT:***

Rearranging the given expresion, we obtain
$$dy=\frac{ydx-xdy}{y^2}=d(\frac{x}{y})$$

Comment: Thanks but I don’t understand what you did, maybe I missed but I don’t remembering learning such technique

Comment: If $y=\frac{u}{v}$, then $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{v\frac{du}{dx}-u\frac{dv}{dx}}{v^2}$ $\Rightarrow dy=\frac{vdu-udv}{v^2}$ I hope you learnt this in your differentiation classes

Comment: A similar concept is used when we have $dy=ydx+xdy=d(xy)$

Comment: Oh yes, now if i understand correctly, we got $dy = d(x/y)$ Integrating we get: $y = x/y + C $. Im just not used to look at this that way, sorry, you right, we surely did learnt that differentiation.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Write it as $$\frac{y-xy'}{y^2}=y'$$ Note that, LHS is derivative of the form $\displaystyle \frac{d(\frac{u}{v})}{dx}$

Answer (score 2):

Substitute $x = vy$ and you will see it simplify.

$(vy+y^2)y' = y \,$

i.e $(v+y)dy = d(vy)$

i.e $(v+y)dy = ydv + vdy$

i.e $dy = dv$

Comment: Working nicely, thanks!

Comment: As you see $y$ on both sides, it is easier to think we should do $x = vy$. Sometimes it is the other way round.

Answer (score 0):

Exchange the roles of the variables, that is, consider $y$ the dependent variable. Then you get a linear differential equation in $x=x(y)$,
$$
x+y^2=yx'.
$$
Now apply the method of the integrating factor, and find the same expressions as in the other answers.

Comment: This is a method i always don’t understand, yet i see her not once, can you explain how you got to $x+y^2 = yx’$ From the original equation?

Comment: On any monotonous segment of the solution curve, you can find an inverse function for $y(x)$. Call it $x=\phi(y)$ to avoid overloading the letter $x$. Then the chain rule implies $x=\phi(y(x))\implies 1=\phi'(y(x))y'(x)$ so that by multiplying the original equation with $\phi'(y)$ the derivatives on the left side cancel out and replacing $x$ with the inverse function gives $\phi(y)+y^2=y\phi'(y)$.

Answer (score 0):

$$(x + y^2)y’ = y$$
$$(x + y^2) = x'y$$
$$\dfrac {x'y-x}{y^2}=1$$
$$\left (\dfrac x y \right)'=1$$
Integrate.